# R 3.5 package ‘lattice’ was installed by an R version with different internals

Tags: r, lattice, r-package

I updated R 3.4.4 to R 3.5.0 today. And my package cannot pass `R CMD check` anymore. It fails at `checking whether package can be installed ... ERROR`.

In another hand my package works, I can install it and use it as long as I don't check it.

The error is the following:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sp’:
 package ‘lattice’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
Error : package ‘sp’ could not be loaded
```

I tried to reinstall `lattice` these ways:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install r-cran-lattice
```

or

```
remove.packages("lattice", lib="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5")
install.package("lattice")
```

The package `lattice` is installed correctly in both cases. But it does not solve my problem. Also I ensured to have a single version of `lattice` removing either the `r-cran` one or the self compiled version. Nothing works.

**Edit** By the way I can do `library(sp)` or `library(lattice)` it works. But not with R CMD check

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you that the *binary* you are attempting to install comes from an insufficient / incompatible R version.

Two fixes:

1. Install from source as you did. After that check with `AP <- available.packages()` that you really only have one.
2. Use the correct binarie: read [this README at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) and switch to Michael's 'R 3.5' repos.  Many of us have been doing that for weeks.

Lastly, the `r-sig-debian` list is a friendly place for these questions and more. Subscribe first so that you can post.

Comment: If you mean using this repo `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/` this is already what I did. This is how I installed R 3.5

Comment: Depending what distro you are on, yes. And then also https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u3.5 for 3000 more.

Comment: So everything is ok on my side in theory. And yet it does not work. So I missed something somewhere.

Comment: Try this: reset `.libPaths()` (there are several ways, see `help(Startup)` -- maybe edit in `/etc/R/Renviron{,.site}`) so that you control _exactly_ what R sees at startup. The add directories one by one.

Comment: Ok it sounds to be an issue with Rstudio or devtools. I built a source package and ran R CMD check on the tarball in a terminal and it worked.